# column that references other columns in the same dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a column that shows the values from other columns. in other words a column that references other columns and shows their values not the definitions or just a 'Yes' or 'No'. Example, this is what I have so far:

```
alter table [dbo].[Mortality2015]
add [Education] varchar(50) null

update [dbo].[Mortality2015]
set [Education] = case
                     when [education_reporting_flag] = 0 
                        then [education_1989_revision]
                     when [education_reporting_flag] = 1 
                        then [education_2003_revision]
                     when [education_reporting_flag] = 2 
                        then null
                  end
```

I get a new column with only null values. Anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: This query seem ok.Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Yeah, looks good to me too. What are the values you see in the column `education_reporting_flag`?

Comment: Are there even any rows with `[education_reporting_flag]=0` or `[education_reporting_flag]=1`? For all other `[education_reporting_flag]` the `CASE ... END` will result in `NULL`. And what's the data type of `[education_reporting_flag]`? Possible it might be an issue with wrong implicit casts too.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desire results.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the issue is with your query.  However, you do not have to add a new "real" column to the data.  You can add a computed column.  This looks like:

```
alter table [dbo].[Mortality2015]
    add Education as (case when [education_reporting_flag] = 0 then [education_1989_revision]
                           when [education_reporting_flag] = 1 then [education_2003_revision]
                      end);
```

Of course, this is basically the same logic as in your version.  What is handy is that `Education` is calculated *when used* so it is always up-to-date.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. Yes, after I posted the question I tried it one last time and it worked! I probably should have deleted the question right away but forgot. I appreciate the help and the suggestion. Cheers